Nuxt3 i18n, Page route for only one locale
I want to create some pages on my Nuxt3 application that are available only for one locale.
For example I have these 2 locales:
i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'fr',
        file: 'locales/fe.json',
        domain: 'https://someurlhere.fr/'
      },
      {
        code: 'de',
        file: 'locales/de.json',
        domain: 'https://someurlhere.com/de/'
      }
    ],
    differentDomains: true,
    defaultLocale: 'fr',
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    detectBrowserLanguage: false
  }

I need to create a page like https://someurlhere.fr/french-only-route.
And I want this page to be available only for French url website. All SEO stuff etc.
One way I was thinking of this to check if domain is not french then return 404.
Is this the best practice? To use a middleware and let it handle this scenario?
Or is there an option to do this via i18n, that I missed on docs?
Many thanks
